# How do I fix this index out of bound error

Tags: java

Main Class

```
        FileDealer.modify(t2, 0, "99999");
        FileDealer.modify(t2, 0, "88888");
```

FileDealer Class (Method: Modify)

```
public static void modify(Ticket t, int type, String newInformation) throws MacAddressLengthException, IOException {
        int index = ticketList.indexOf(t);
        Ticket toModify = null;
        toModify = ticketList.get(index);
        switch (type) {
        case 0: // adding mainID
            toModify.setMainID(Utility.convertInt(newInformation));
            break;
        case 1: // adding assetID
            toModify.setAssetID(Utility.convertInt(newInformation));
            break;
        case 2: // adding macAdd
            toModify.setMacAdd(newInformation);
            break;
        case 3: // edit
            toModify.setNote(newInformation);
            break;
        case 4: // delete
            ticketList.remove(index);
        }
        updateFile();
        readFile();
    }
```

when the modify method is called the first time it is able to edit the ticket details, but when it is called the 2nd time, the `int index = ticketList.indexOf(t)` from the method returns a "-1" even though nothing changed, and it gives me an exception for the index being out of bound. How do I change that -1 to show the right index?

Comment: If an entry isn't in the `ticketList`, then `indexOf` will return `-1`.  In the first loop, if you hit `case 4` and _remove_ it from the `List`, then this will be what happens the second time through.

Comment: Your code looks correct, maybe an error is coming from the way you are updating the list items

Comment: Please, how does your `Ticket` class looks like?

Comment: @BeUndead since this is in a loop (i only took out the error part), it works the first time when I run it all the numbers are correct but on the 2nd time of the loop when I try to look for the same ticket again the index returns a -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs if `t2` is not in the `ticketList` - so there are two `equal` objects: one is `t2` and the other is in the `ticketList`:

```
static List<Ticket> ticketList = Arrays.asList(
    new Ticket(1, 1, "one", "one"), 
    new Ticket(2, 2, "two", "two"), 
    new Ticket(3, 3, "drei", "drei")
);
// ...
Ticket t2 = new Ticket(2, 2, "two", "two");

modify(t2, 0, "99999");
modify(t2, 0, "88888");
```

Most likely, methods `equals` and `hashCode` are overridden in class `Ticket` and they use the values of the member fields to define equality.

Then, method `modify` updates existing value `toModify` within the list, and possibly the `ticketList` is completely rebuilt inside calls to `updateFile`, `readFile`.

Thus, `t2` becomes outdated because `ticketList` does not contain a ticket with old `mainID` any longer and `indexOf` returns -1.

This can be overcome if the reference `t2` is initially bound to some object within the `ticketList` -- then it becomes updated outside method `modify`:

```java
Ticket t2 = ticketList.get(1);
modify(t2, 0, "99999");
modify(t2, 0, "88888");
```

Comment: thanks I noticed that my loop was a little too small and did not refresh the list after being updated, its working now

Answer (score 3):

Probably the `equals` method of the `Ticket` class depends in any way of the `mainID` field, and it seems that you modify that field in the `modify` method.

As a consequence, the second time you invoke `modify`, `indexOf` returns `-1` because `equals` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: 5 minutes before the accepted one....well, sometimes happens. Restoring karma here

Comment: Thank you very much @aran. Yes, you are right... Although I must recognize that the accepted answer is very well written and detailed, entirely reserves to be marked as the correct one. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the index is equal to -1 then print a clear message and skip the process cause the ticket will not be there.
indexOf returns -1 if there is no matching, so you could add this if:

```
if(index < 0){
 System.out.print("ticket not exists!");
 break;
}
```

Comment: the thing is when it runs the first time, it works perfectly fine, i just plucked out the part that was having issues since this part should be in a loop. the first time it runs in the loop it does what its supposed to do but on the 2nd time it just returns a -1 when nothing changed

Comment: actually there no problem with your code. but  as you are getting the ticket object from the list by index. this will give you an error anytime this index is not there.

Comment: you send the same t2 in both times, so your code must be enters the 4th case in the switch, in the second time the indexOf return -1, and when you try to get that object. it gives you out of bound exception.

Comment: won't the breaks at the end of every case prevent that from happening?

Comment: it is not getting in to the first three cases, the first time it gets the index correctly then get the ticket from the list by using the get toModify = ticketList.get(index);. after that it matches the case number 4. so the ticket deleted from the ticketList. in the second time the first line int index = ticketList.indexOf(t); returns -1 as the ticket is not in the list anymore. then the get in the third line gives an exception as the ticket is not there.

Comment: did you get the steps ?. is there any question ?

Comment: i tried printing the arraylist and none of them are getting removed from the list; and if you look at the code above it shouldn't enter case 4 since i specified type to be 0?
Also, when I did it the first round and printed the arraylist, ```t2``` was modified but when i try to modifiy it again it just gives a -1 even though the changes can be seen after the first modification

Comment: try to print the index in both cases

Comment: assuming t2 is at index of 0, when i print it the first time of the loop the index i get is 0, which is correct, all changes made can be seen during the first loop, but when i try to do it a second time, the index becomes -1 which leads to the exception. I understand how the exception come about since -1 is out of bounds, but what I dont understand is how the index becomes -1 when nothing has changed

Comment: that just adds some new data to the ticket, the initial mainID for the ticket is -1 and convertInt is basically just ```Integer.parseInt(string)```

Comment: @ElliotChin, you have different objects `t2` and its equal counterpart inside the list.  After the first call to `modify` the counterpart changes and cannot be found any longer if methods `equals/hashCode` use `mainID` to compare `Ticket` instances - check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814822/13279831)